# How to roll back/undo edits?

Tags: discussion, editing

I can't seem to find the functionality to roll back an edit that was accidently approved. How do you do go back to an earlier revision of a post?

(on a side note: ppl seem to approve edits too hurriedly..)

Comment: Can you provide a link so I can have a look. When you go into edit history you should be able to see an option against previous versions to roll back.

Comment: @RoryAlsop - http://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/38136/needs-to-learn-music-mixing-basis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the rep to roll back an edit it will show when you go into edit history for that post. cClick on the last edited time, eg "edited 4hrs ago" and then click on the word Rollback next to the version you want to roll back to.

In that specific instance, I think the edit was actually a dramatic improvement over the original, which I would have closed instantly as a shopping question. It is still marginal, but at least may attract useful answers now.

Comment: Ahh.. probably my rep is too low then. Yeah I don't disagree about the overall improvement of a bad question, but.. when the editor removes details and changes the meaning, something is wrong.. a dialogue with the author should be engaged

Comment: Actually - I agree with you on that. The last part specifically changes the meaning a fair bit.

Comment: I have reverted it to the original version and left a comment